# Symfony 4 CollectionType not creating the fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to combine multiple forms in Symfony 4. I have a `Files` entity that requires a relation with the `Translate` entity. So in the form used to create the new `File`, I need to implement a field for the translation.

Here's part of my code :

```
$builder
    ...
    ->add('translationDefinition', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => TranslationType::class
    ])
    ...
    ->add('Enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
```

My `TranslationType` looks like this :

```
$builder
    ->add('frValue', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Traduction fr'
    ])
```

But this code isn't working. It only prints "Translation definition" in the form (I'm guessing it's the label). I've read [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html), but after hours of searching I can't really find the solution to the problem, so I'm hoping someone could help me figure this out. Did I miss something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the doc for the [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage).

> *No input fields would render unless your `translationDefinitionalready` contained some `translations`*

So you need to render the initial fields by hand with the help of the prototype. Or you can create an empty child initially.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I create an empty child (and what do you mean by an empty child ?) and then how do I persist the translate object to the database ?